# LaTeX: Beamer with \newcommand

Tags: beamer, macros

I have tons of slides starting with

```
\bslide
```

I tried to rephrase my source for class Beamer by defining

```
\newcommand{\bslide}{\begin{frame}{xxx}}
```

Unfortunately LaTeX says

```
===========================================
[1] (./sliBeamer.tex (./titBeamer.tex)
Runaway argument?
 \par 
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.15 \input{titBeamer}

? x
Output written on slidesBeamer.dvi (1 page, 22680 bytes).
Transcript written on slidesBeamer.log.
make: *** [slidesBeamer.dvi] Error 1
======================================
```

Any hint?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: How do you *end* your slides?  Is there an `\eslide` command, or does each `\bslide` mark the end of the previous slide as well as the start of the next?  (Either way, I think the easiest would be to do a search-and-replace in an editor.  beamer looks for the explicit `\end{frame}` text when looking for the end of a frame.)

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your comment. Yes: I defined an "\eslide" as \newcommand{\eslide}{\end{frame}}. If I understand well your response, I MUST insert an explicit \end{frame} at the end of each slide. I hoped the "\eslide" command does the work: I should like not to change the source of my slides.

Answer (score 4):

Some environments that do 'clever' things don't like shorthand macros of this type. Another example is the `align` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Shamelessly borrowing from the [technical details](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf) for `amsmath`, I suggest the following.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\long\def\bslide#1\eslide{\begin{frame}{xxx}#1\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\bslide
This is a nice slide
\eslide
\end{document}
```